# Notation for hypergeometric functions

Tags: notation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I know about the usual notation for referring to hypergeometric functions, such as $_pF_q$.

However, I've found something like $\boxed{_p\tilde{F}_q}$ as a part of the expression for calculating the raw moments of a random variable following a doubly noncentral $F$ distribution in this web page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralF-Distribution.html . I had never seen that before.

What does $_p\tilde{F}_q$ stand for?

Comment: It seems that page neglected to define that symbol. Anyway, it is a [regularized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: @J.M. Yes, they did not define what it is. That is why I asked it here. Would you like to post your contribution as an answer?

Comment: This is a very simple question, but I was not able to find the answer in any other way, so I think it may be useful for other people having the same doubt that me in the future.

Comment: Is that notation used anywhere other than Wolfram/Mathematica?

Comment: @GEdgar As far as I know, yes, but I didn't know it when I asked this question. Anyway, I think it is a simple but interesting question. I suggested moving it to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the function they neglected to define in the MathWorld link is what they term the ["regularized hypergeometric function"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html),

$${}_p \tilde{F}_q\left({{a_1,\dots,a_p}\atop{b_1,\dots,b_q}}\middle|x\right)=\frac1{\prod\limits_{k=1}^q\Gamma(b_k)}{}_p F_q\left({{a_1,\dots,a_p}\atop{b_1,\dots,b_q}}\middle|x\right)$$

i.e., the usual hypergeometric function divided by the product of gamma functions evaluated at the denominator parameters.

---

In the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.v), the term "scaled" or "Olver's hypergeometric function" is used, with the notation ${}_p\mathbf{F}_q\left(\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z\right)$.